# Is there any way to keep track of a counter for a button click in AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a scenario, say user is trying to sign in and trying with wrong password. If the attempt is crossed the limit of 5 times then i need to lock the account.( I know there is an efficient locking mechanism is there in B2C, but that won't work for me.) To do so i need to maintain a counter to know how many times the user clicked the login button. Is there any way to do this B2C custom policy?

Comment: Why the B2C mechanism doesn't work for you?

Comment: I need to lock the account and i have another user flow, there user need to unlock the account by verifying the email.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand why the default locking mechanism would prevent doing that.

Comment: As per my understanding B2C will lock the account for a time that we configuring in B2C setting and unlocks the user after that time automatically. In my case that won't work, until user unlock his/her account user is not allowed to login. If I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: Ahh okay, I get it now :) You could use a custom claim that you store as an extension property on the user. Not sure if mathematical operations were available in claims transformations so you could use them to increment it..

Comment: I have the custom claim but i didn't find any claim transformations to do increment operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Custom REST API](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api#azure-ad-b2c-integrate-rest-api-claims-exchanges-and-input-validation) that stores the lockdown state and call it from B2C using a [REST Technical Profile](http://Define%20a%20RESTful%20technical%20profile%20in%20an%20Azure%20Active%20Directory%20B2C%20custom%20policy).

Comment: Or the lockdown state can use a custom claim, but increment it etc. using a REST TP (since there doesn't seem to be claims transformations for incrementing integers).

Comment: Yeah, I have plan to do that. But was checking is there any easier way to do this. Thanks

Comment: @Alex You will need to use a custom claim type always to store the value in/during the journey but to persist it in the long run regardless of session or device you need to do that in the REST API.